# Store Auth Token securely in Backbone app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, backbone.js, token, marionette

I'm starting a Marionette on Rails application and I'm looking for a secure way to authenticate requests. I'm sure this has been done by many but I could not find a satisfying answer :(

Here is what I've found so far:

- In rails, I can generate a token with `Devise.friendly_token`, save it in the database and send it to the client.
- The client can store the token in meta data of the page that is secured from CSRF.
- At each request, the client would send the token in the header with

  `var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);`

and the server would compare the tokens to authenticate the request. So far so good.

- I've read in different places that cookies are vulnerable to cross domain requests. However persistent cookies seem to be the only solution for persistent sessions. How can I use them in a secure way?
- On an other note, I've seen that it is recommended to hash the password on the client side before sending it to the server. For a API based service, what is the interest of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) APIs for persistent storage.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to store the authorization token in your app as a variable. For example,

```
// app.js

var app = {
  views: {},
  models: {},
  collections: {},
  routers: {},
  utils: {},
  adapters: {},
  session: {}
};
```

When the user logs in, the server will send the Devise.friendly_token back to client side. You could save that access token in the app and protect yourself from CSRF attacks. This method does, however, open you up to other types of attacks if the attacker has access to the user's browser.

```
// LoginView.js
app.views.LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({

// ...
    login: function(event){
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('email', $('#email').val());
        data.append('password', $('#password').val());
        $.ajax({
            url: API_ROOT + "api/v1/login",
            data: data, 
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
              app.session.userEmail = data.email;
              app.session.userAccessToken = data.access_token;
            },
            error: function(data){
              alert('Login failed');
         }
      });
    },
// ...
});
```

Once the token is stored, send it in an authorization header with your requests to your API server.

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
// ... override the Backbone.sync function. See the annotated source code for more
// info.

  options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', ("" + app.session.userAccessToken));
  }

//... also send for POST

if (options.emulateHTTP && (type === 'PUT' || type === 'DELETE' || type === 'PATCH')) {
    params.type = 'POST';
    if (options.emulateJSON) params.data._method = type;
    var beforeSend = options.beforeSend;
    options.beforeSend = function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-HTTP-Method-Override', type);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', ("" + app.session.userAccessToken));
      if (beforeSend) return beforeSend.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  }

//...
};
```

This method is far from perfect, as it allows attackers with access to the browser to get the user's access token. One way to add an extra layer of security may be to renew access tokens after an interval on the server side. Hope this at least starts some discussion on better ways to implement this.